# How To Publish a Windows form (C#) application on windows store

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am new to Windows Development. And as per criteria of my Internship they want an application from me on windows store whether UWP, WPF or Windows form. Now as I made an application on Windows form(C#). My question is that how to publish my application on windows store? Or  whether a Windows form application can be published to store or not. Or I have to make a WPF or UWP application?

Answer (score 2):

As a developer who creates some apps for the Windows Store, I think that you can only submit UWP. Because Visual Studio only generates store packages if you are working in a UWP project.

However, Microsoft is working in [Project Centennial](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51691) a desktop to store app converter.

Comment: In addition to @ganchito55's response, you might follow the [MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to convert your app to UWP packages. After you finish, you could complete [this form](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge) to submit your publishing request and wait for the response from related team. The process may take a couple of weeks.

Comment: There exists also an [article from Scott](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PuttingMyVB6WindowsAppsInTheWindows10StoreProjectCentennial.aspx), describing the project.

Comment: It's not more Project Centennial - it's called Desktop Bridge now